# Bracketing in awk patterns

Tags: awk

I have seen regex patterns using either character classes (e.g. `[:alpha:]`, `[:digit:]`) or directly specifying the characters themselves (e.g. `[a-zA-Z]`, `[0-9]`).

Are the enclosing square brackets `[...]` always required when using `[:alpha:]` and `[:digit:]`.  Are the enclosing square brackets `[...]` simply the enclosing square brackets in `[a-zA-Z]` and `[0-9]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try it out yourself, running through `ASCII` characters from `"!"` to `"~"` :

> ```
> jot -c - 33 126 | mawk '/[:digit:]/'
> ```

```
:
d
g
i
t
```

> ```
> jot -c - 33 126 | mawk '/[[:digit:]]/'
> ```

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

> ```
> jot -c - 33 126 | mawk '/[0-9]/'
> ```

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

> ```
> jot -c - 33 126 | mawk '/[[0-9]]/'
> ```

```
** absolutely nothing matches **, but would print 
                2 out of 4 if this were the input :
```

> ```
> echo '][\n[]\n[-9+]\n8]' | 
> gtee >( gcat -n >&2; )   | mawk '/[[0-9]]/'
> ```

```
     1  ][
     2  []
     3  [-9+]
     4  8]

[]
8]
```

since `[[0-9]]` matches :

- `literal "[" or any "0-9",`
- `immediately followed by one literal "]"`

Comment: I do not understand the reason why the equivalence to `[0-9]` is `[[:digit:]]` with double `[[ ...]]`.

Comment: Hopefully your system supports `info awk` and `info sed` . Sometimes you have to look at the `sed` documentation to get the "official truth" about a feature.  From `info sed` : `These named classes must be used _inside_ brackets themselves.
Correct usage:
     $ echo 1 | sed 's/[[:digit:]]/X/'
    (output=) X`  That is to say, "That's the way it is designed". Stop worrying about it, there is so much more to learn! Good luck.

Comment: Learn to trust and create your won  simple tests as demonstrated above. AND do them everytime you are changing systems or installing an update to an affected tool or library.Very  ocassionally you'll find that different systems implement features creating unusual corner cases that may affect your data processing.  ... You'll find differences between Mac based OS, Linux, AIX, HP Linux, etc, etc. Also note that `*awk` and `sed` (on the same system) (almost certainly) link in  the same `regex` library to do this processing.

Comment: @shellter : i never spoke about `sed` now did I ? I didn't even mention the word `sed` in any casing, or hinted at it.  as for `awk`, what I stated above is true, and performs exactly as what I've described in `macOS nawk` `mawk1` `mawk2` and `gawk 5`, so unless you're using some absolutely pure junk `awk`s like `busybox awk` or whatever crap inside `Solaris`, then I don't see what's the issue here.  `sed` is one of those things I try to avoid like the plague.

Comment: @shellter : and what the heck is `HP Linux` ?? There's `HP-UX` that was abandoned by 2010, and some `HP` laptops sold today with `Ubuntu distro of Linux` (at best , very lightly customized, as opposed to a full scale distro divergence on their own.

Comment: @shellter : maybe you also didn't realize `info` is actually something for `gnu` apps instead of anything mandated by `POSIX`. And you're thoroughly confusing two things - the char class works as desired only if inside square brackets for `awk`, yes, but being outside of them is still a valid `ERE regex`, just matching something unrelated instead. And use those char classes at your own peril  : `gawk` in unicode mode doesn't think  `63680 {  } U+ F8C0` or `65298 {２} U+ FF12` or `9374 { ⒞ } U+ 249E`  belong to `[[:alnum:]]`

Comment: Yep, sorry it wasn't clear that my comments where in reply to @Roger 's initial comment. If you look at hist qustion history, you'll see he's been spending a lot of time on these questions.  I am trying to encourage him to learn to do his own research. Sorry for the misstatement of numerous facts. I will try to rewrite these tomorrow. It's late where I live. Good luck to all!